# Wordpress Query Crashes Browser

Tags: php, plugin-development

I have this code below that gets each child category from a specific taxonomy. There are two things I would like to get help with:

Refactoring to wordpress
Why does it crash.

```
<?php 
$customPostTaxonomies = get_object_taxonomies('recipe');

$categories = [];
if(count($customPostTaxonomies) > 0)
{
    foreach($customPostTaxonomies as $tax)
    {
        $args = array(
            'orderby' => 'name',
            'show_count' => 0,
            'pad_counts' => 0,
            'hierarchical' => 1,
            'taxonomy' => $tax,
            'title_li' => '',
            'echo' => false,
            'separator'=> ',',
            'style' => 'none'
        );

        array_push($categories, wp_list_categories( $args ));
    }
}
$mergedArray = '';
foreach($categories as $element)
{   
    $mergedArray .= $element;
}
$mergedArray = explode(',', $mergedArray);
$allCategories = [];
foreach($mergedArray as $recipesCategory){
    $recipesCategory = str_replace('</a>','',$recipesCategory);
    $recipesCategory = substr($recipesCategory, strpos($recipesCategory, '" >')+3, strlen($recipesCategory));
    array_push($allCategories, $recipesCategory);
}
wp_reset_postdata();
//getting category
global $wpdb;               
foreach($allCategories as $cat){
    //geting category data
    $results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM `wp_term_taxonomy` tax JOIN `wp_terms` term on tax.term_id = term.term_id and term.name = '".$cat."' ", OBJECT );
    $categoryData = $results[0];
    if($categoryData->taxonomy != 'recipe' && $categoryData->taxonomy != 'recipe_category'){
        continue;
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();

    //getting posts by category
    $the_query = new WP_Query( array( 
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'recipe',
                'terms' => $categoryData->name,
                'field'    => 'name'
            ),
        ),
        'posts_per_page' => 12,
    ));
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
?>

<div class="row recipe-archive-list">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) { ?>
                ....                
        } ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly happens, when "it" crashes? What's in the error log?

Comment: It shows up the "Oh, no" message from Chrome. The code itself it's not giving me an error, it just loads for a moment and then crashes.

Comment: What about your server's error log? Do you have display_errors and display_startup_errors enabled?